# django: customized decorator running before django-rest-framework authentication class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My REST APIs:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
@method_decorator(operation_logger)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(FileView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request):
    print "xxxxpost"
```

The customized decorator:

```
def operation_logger(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print "xxxx"
        comments = []
        psfile = None
        op = None
        remote_addr = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        if request.user:
            user = request.user
            print request.user.username
        else:
            print "request.user is None"

        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

It seems that my decorator running before authentication finished. How to fix it?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I added my middleware list below. But I am not sure it is related, because I created a branch new app for APIs, which is using djangorestframework.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'lib.middleware.SessionTimeout',
    'lib.middleware.ForceTemporaryPasswordChange'
)
```

Comment: what is your middleware order? http://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order your decorators are applied: the one nearest to `def` line will run first.

```
@method_decorator(operation_logger)
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(FileView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```